# Clear the excel file after download it to reuse in PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, phpexcel

I am creating excel file with single worksheet using PHPExcel.

I have managed to do this but the issue came after when I created it ones then it didn't get clear so when I am creating it again the the previous data came along with the new data.

So I am just want to **clear** the **excel** file **before using it again**.

**Here is the code:**

```
require_once APPPATH.'third_party/PHPExcel.php';
require_once APPPATH.'third_party/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

//Getting Data form database

$bTob_gstdata = $this->reports_model->get_bTob_gstdata($date_from, $date_to);

//Sample Excel File (which is clear already Just contain the structure)
$filename =  'assets/btob_base_excel.xls';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filename);

echo $filetype = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filename);
$excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($filetype);
$excel2 = $excel2->load('assets/btob_base_excel.xls'); // Empty Sheet
$excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$t=0;

$total_invoice_count = 0;
$recipients_count   = array();
$invoice_count      = array();
for($k=5;$k<(count($bTob_gstdata)+5);$k++)
{
    //Adding Data in Excel WorkSheet
    $excel2->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('A'.$k, $bTob_gstdata[$t]["dist_gstin"]);
    $t++;

}

$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A3', (count($recipients_count)));
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B3', (count($invoice_count)));
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D3', '=SUM(D5:D'.(count($bTob_gstdata)+5).')');
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('J3', '=SUM(J5:J'.(count($bTob_gstdata)+5).')');
$excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, $filetype);
$objWriter->save('btocl_gst_report.xls'); //Saving the excel file
header("location:".base_url("btob_gst_report.xls")); // Downloading the excel file
```

**I want to clear the created excel file to Reuse**

Comment: the issue is you aren't creating it, you're just loading it from disk and manipulating it. I suggest you just delete the file at the end, and create a whole new file at the beginning (google to how to create a new excel file using phpexcel, rather than loading one)

Comment: Ok i get what you are saying sir but my pre-loaded excel file is empty(clear)  @ADyson sir

Comment: I am loading it because i need some static data already filled up in the excel. @ADyson sir

Comment: in that case, in your code make a copy of your file, load the copy using phpexcel, modify it, send it to the user and delete it at some time afterwards. It will be much easier than trying to undo all your changes. BTW you are going to have to make this an offline process later on, because if you delete the file during this PHP script, it may delete it before the user makes the download request. It would be the same problem if you tried to undo the changes. Perhaps a cron job should clean up the folder every few hours or something.

Comment: I will surely keep that in mind sir..  @ADyson thx